# Error with generated view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

What is wrong with the following code?  It was generated by teh add view wizard. And when I navigate to the controller I get the following error: `String was not recognised as a valid Boolean`  and the following line is highlighted:  @using (Html.BeginForm())

Here is the view:

```
  @model Radio_Management_Interface.DomainModel.Entities.Network

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_main.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Network</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.startCode, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.startCode)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.startCode)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.frequency, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.frequency)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.frequency)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}`
```

Controller:

```
//
    // GET: /Networks/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Network network = db.Networks.Find(id);
        if (network == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(network);
    }
```

Domain Model:

```
   public class Network
{
    public int networkID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int startCode { get; set; }
    public decimal frequency { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Block> blocks { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That is my entire view file. I will add controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your id is a nullable type, replace it with this line instead:

```
  Network network = db.Networks.Find(id.Value);
```

And this:

```
 if (id == null)
```

Can be changed to this:

```
 if (!id.HasValue)
```

The problem will be with the following line:

```
Network network = db.Networks.Find(id);
```

The id is actually a nullable type that is passed to your Find method when it is expecting the value.

With nullable types you can read the underlying value with the Value property i.e.

```
id.Value
```

Comment: My Id should be an int? Shouldn't it? I added my model to the question.

Comment: Yes of course, but as it's a nullable type you need to set the value rather than the object. I will update the question to explain a bit better. :)

Comment: Ok that worked perfectly for my details action.  But now I am receiving the same error on the Create action.  here is the action method `  public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }`

Comment: Ok, please could you create another question with the code within it? It's just easier to track, post the link on here and I'll take a look. :)

Comment: Also pls could you post the razor for the create too in the new question, I think I would need to see that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235101/getting-error-with-create-action-method-return-view